# Looking for e-newsletter sending application recommendation

Tags: email

no matter paid or free
, web application or software, please kindly give some suggestion, thanks a lot

Looking for:

- Privacy
- Convenience
- user - friendly
- price

Also, which choice would be better? Send from local host or by the mail service provider( eg.gmail server) Thanks again

Comment: http://www.mailchimp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few options here. The most popular ones are:

1. Mailchimp
2. Sendgrid
3. Amazon SES
4. Postmark
5. Campaign Monitor
6. Constant Contact